# Uncheck Checkbox depend on another activity

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-checkbox

In Main Activity Add icon . There will be checkbox list dialog will appear. when click on checkbox user can check their desire url link. When **checkbox** is checked, that Two EditText will saved to db.  Two EditText were Invisible. It's will be list in Another Activity. If user don't like added url. They can delete by popup dialog call delete. 
My problems  is that when user delete url, i want to uncheck in List of CheckBox on Dialog.

Note* Checkbox list are manually added.

Thanks. If you have additional question pls ask me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two approaches:

1. Pass state of checkbox from one Activity to another through `Intent`. Based on the state of checkbox received through Intent in second activity, make changes in your UI.

   boolean state = [getStateOfCheckBox];
   intent.putExtra("Key", state);
   startActivity(intent);

   //Get the state in receiver Activity's onCreate()
   Intent receiveIntent = getIntent(); 
   boolean checkBoxState = receiverIntrent.getBooleanExtra("Key");
2. Save the state of checkbox in `SharedPreferences` in first Activity and retrieve the value in Second Activity.

   //Save state in SharedPreferences
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSHaredPreferences("YourSharedPreferencesName", "Mode");
   SharedPreferences.Editor = editor = prefs.edit();
   editor.putBoolean("Key", state).commit();

   //Extract state at receiver's end
   SharedPreferences prefs = getSHaredPreferences("YourSharedPreferencesName", "Mode");
   boolean state = prefs.getBoolean("Key", "DefaultState");

Comment: Thanks. i'm still doesn't get it. Can you show me some code?

Comment: Updated answer with code. You may need to make some changes in the code. Let me know if you find any issue

Comment: It's pass checkbox state from activity to another. In my requirement, I need to pass that delete item to uncheck in CheckBox dialog list. Is it possible? I have no idea bcoz i have added checkbox list manually.

Comment: You can pass any data to other activity. You can even in the form of string